# Same Symbol but two UTF-8 in Javascript (.normalize() can not resolve)

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, utf-8

- I have issue with Unicode symbol. Like the title, previous, i use .normalize() function to convert two symbol to standard utf-8 code. I think it will cover all my casse but it does not .
- The two "Đ" symbol in my case have 2 utf-8 code: \xC3\x90 and \xC4\x90. You can check it out https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal 
  And javascript normalize function can not convert them to only one utf-8 code.
- I need your suggest. A block of code or library, anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those are simply two different letters, an uppercase Eth (U+00D0) and an uppercase D with a stroke (U+0110). They're not interchangeable, so they don't normalise to the same characters. Even if they happen to look the same.

The same is true for many other characters. For example, the Russian letter С (U+0421) looks just like a C (U+0043), but it's not the same letter; when transliterating Russian to ASCII you'd get an S.

So you can't convert all lookalikes to each other; not without loss of information.

If you explain what your use case is exactly, maybe someone can come up with a solution for that. But there is no general library that can solve the problem of some characters looking just like others.

Comment: Your (now deleted) comment said Google search did it, but do you mean you can type Ð into Google and it also finds pages with the other Đ? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yeah google search, visual code may be more. I am searching for a mapped data file which cover all other cases.